# What is the difference between "Super Mario Advance 4/Super Mario Bros 3" and "Super Mario Advance" on the Game Boy Advance SP?

Tags: game-boy-advance, super-mario-bros, super-mario-advance-4

I am wondering because it seems that some GBA games were released that copied the "concept" of "Super Mario All Stars" on the Super Nintendo, which is to redesign classic games and resell them for a recent platform.

I don't understand, though, which games are contained in which cartridge, and whether you need to buy several cartridges to have Super Mario 1, 2 and 3 on the GBA... And why Super Mario Bros 3 is called "Super Mario Advance 4 and not Advance 3 or 2... Are there Advance 2 and 3??
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were 4 Super Mario Advances released.  The Advance games were simply renumbered in order of release on GBA and do not respect the order of the original games - they worked on the ports and rereleases based on Nintendo's internal choices.  They eventually figured out that it might be better to include the original name to prevent confusion, which is why you see Advance 4 labelled, but not Advance 1.

Super Mario Advance - this is Super Mario Bros 2. from the NES.

Super Mario Advance 2 - This is Super Mario World from the SNES.

Super Mario Advance 3 - This is Yoshi's Island from the SNES.

Super Mario Advance 4 - this is Super Mario Bros 3 from the NES.

The original Super Mario Bros. from the NES era was not released under the Advance updated rereleases for the GBA.  Although some of the carts included a port of Mario Bros. (a single-screen game where you clear out critters in a sewer)

Comment: The original Super Mario Bros. had just been released as Super Mario Bros. Deluxe for the GameBoy Color.